# Free Java HTML and JS parser

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, parsing

Do you know a parser which could operate on AJAX and has option to override method of connecting (I would like to use my own method to connect to pages).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you should give [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) a try.

Answer (score 2):

LoboBrowser: http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp
with this library you can run HTML and JS over Java

```
1) Connect to a specific URL and get the response
2) Browse the response using LoboBrowser
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

but I don't know if you can override connect method